# Dispose Active x object on close of the browser and browser gets crashed

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, activex

I have a parent window which opens child windows using window.open()

In the child window there is an ActiveX object

```
 <object classid="CLSID:9358808d-3766-43fc-b39d-5b8132137f38" id="Control"
        width="100%" height="100%">
    </object>
```

So on each of the child window that i open there is an active x object loaded.
Now the problem is after opening and closing such, in  multiple tabs the browser gets crashed at some point.I suspect that on close of the window the active x object is not getting disposed..

One solution I tried is in the registry,For my DLL which i am creating the ActiveX object i tried changing ThreadingModel to Apartment..

Thanks for the Help in advance..